# All facebook functions disappeared on my website?

Tags: facebook

I am using two wordpress plugins on my website (gründerzeit.de) to insert facebook functions.
The first one is "Add Link to Facebook" with which I implemented -among others- the facebook widget.
The second one is "GetSocial" wich I use for the social media buttons.

They worked fine together!

The strange thing is, that all the functions just disappeared without any error message or something.

I already updated the FB-app and made all the Oct. changes.

Hope anybody will know what to do :)

Thank you very much in advance.

Best,
Andy